# Vaadin Tabsheet undesired refreshing of tab content

Tags: java, tabs, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a Vaadin-TabSheet which has a BrowserFrame in each tab. I notice the following undesired behavior: When I change the tab by clicking on it, the browserframe reloads, possibly erasing any inputs the user might have made in that tab.

How can I keep the tab from reloading? Is there an alternative to the tabSheet?

Comment: Simulate a tabsheet with buttons and then setVisible(true/false) of the elements should probably do the trick

Comment: To add to that: this is how the TabSheet works.  It shows one Tab and on change roundtrips to the server and the new content replaces the old one. It is not your regular hidden-content tabs we know from jquery etc.

Answer (score 0):

I now have built my own TabSheet.
I tried to use setVisible on the tab contents, but this also made the browser frame reload. So i came up with the following code to change the size of contents:

```
private final HorizontalLayout buttons;
private final GridLayout contents;

/**
 * Construct a new MyTabSheet
 */
public MyTabSheet() {
    buttons = new HorizontalLayout();
    contents = new GridLayout();
....

        if(t.isSelected()) {
            selectedComponent = t.getComponent();
        } else {
            t.getComponent().setSizeUndefined();
            t.getComponent().setWidth(0.0f, Unit.PIXELS);
            t.getComponent().setHeight(0.0f, Unit.PIXELS);
        }
    }

    if(null != selectedComponent) {
        String frameHeight;
        if(selectedComponent instanceof BrowserFrame) {
            BrowserFrame bf = (BrowserFrame)selectedComponent;
            frameHeight = (String) bf.getData();
        } else {
            frameHeight = "800px";
        }
        selectedComponent.setSizeFull();
        selectedComponent.setHeight(frameHeight);
    }
```